# How to store the number in a secure way? using Chainlink VRF generator

Tags: security, random, solidity, chainlink

I have managed to run ChainLink VRF generator on my contract which stores a numbers in a public array. How can I use it in a secure way? I'm not an expert, just started with solidity but to my understanding basically everything from the contract can be read.

To be more specific. ChainLink VRF gives me nice big random number as uint stored in array. Is storing it already reveal the number to a potential hacker? Or in what way could I manipulate the data to make it unreadable from the outside?

The thing I am trying to do is to make a simple contract with guessing the number function. In order to make it less predictable I want to use ChainLink VRF to generate a number for the contract, but if you could read the generated number stored in a contract and then have whatever syntax is written for the function, you should be able to know the number, right? Even if keccak is used, you can just run it outside of the contract and compare results, right?

Answer (score 0):

if you're just using the random number(s) written by Chainlink VRF, you don't necessarily need to store the number.  The random numbers are generally a bit too large to reasonably expect people to guess, so you may want to confine it to a range between 0 to 100 in which case you would want to modulo the random number returned by VRF by 101 (` numToGuess = vrfRandNum % 101)

you can store that target number in storage. If you want to store the VRF random number itself you can store it to a variable `uint private s_vrfRandNum`

If it's private, then the only way to read it is through a getter function. And you could add "require" logic to that function so that it only reads from storage if the owner of the contract is the one calling it.

You can do that by having the require logic inside your getter function or using a solidity [function modifier](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/structure-of-a-contract.html#function-modifiers).

Here is an [example from stack overflow](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110780/how-do-i-give-access-to-only-owner-to-call-the-function).

Comment: so it wouldnt be possible to use it in a public function for people to guess because it would have to get it as requirement to compare with the input number and then you could actually see it anyways right? thanks for answering :) i was told private wont give me that kind of security to use it for this purpose and maybe that could be the reason why.